# Text column side by side minipage

Tags: pdftex, two-column, minipage

I hope to be clear in the following question. I want to create a Newsletter with latex, in which the first non-blank page contains one gray column (highlighted, as it were), and under this in a separated box, another little gray column. Besides, on the side of this, I would like to have other normal text.
I am using the `\minipage` environment with a `two columns` setting, but I don't really know how it works, and I can't get my wanted result. I cen get the two grey columns one under the other, but then the column of normal text moves on the next page.
Here is some code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=1cm, bmargin=0.2cm, tmargin=1cm, rmargin=1cm, centering, includefoot,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} %pagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\definecolor{boxgray}{RGB}{139,137,137}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\colorbox{boxgray}{
\begin{minipage}[t]{60mm} 
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.95\linewidth}
        \color{black} 
        \textbf{\large Contents}
        \begin{itemize}
            \parskip = 0pt
            \item Text
            \item Text
            \item Text
            \item Text
            \item Text
        \end{itemize}

        \parskip = 14pt
        \centerline {\rule{.75\linewidth}{.25pt}}

        \textbf{Lorem Ipsum1}
        \parskip = 3pt

        \lipsum[2]
        \lipsum[4]

    \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}}\hfill

\colorbox{boxgray}{
\begin{minipage}{30mm}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.65\linewidth} 
        \color{black} 
        \textbf{\large Contacts}
        \begin{itemize}
            \parskip = 0pt
            \item Text
            \item Text
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}}\hfill

\begin{minipage}[t!]{.375\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{\Large Lorem Ipsum2}
    \end{center}
    \parskip = 5pt

    \lipsum[1-2]

\end{minipage}\hfill
```

I compile with `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are telling LaTeX to fill in all the horizontal space to the right of your left boxes so there isn't room for anything else on that page. To avoid this, wrap the boxes in an outer `minipage` environment something like the following. I've also made your minimal example a bit more minimal by eliminating unneeded preamble. Note that you don't need `color` as well as `xcolor` in any case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=1cm, bmargin=0.2cm, tmargin=1cm, rmargin=1cm, centering, includefoot,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{boxgray}{RGB}{139,137,137}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{minipage}[t]{60mm}
  \colorbox{boxgray}{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{60mm}
      \centering
      \begin{minipage}[t]{.95\linewidth}
          \color{black}
          \textbf{\large Contents}
          \begin{itemize}
              \parskip = 0pt
              \item Text
              \item Text
              \item Text
              \item Text
              \item Text
          \end{itemize}

          \parskip = 14pt
          \centerline {\rule{.75\linewidth}{.25pt}}

          \textbf{Lorem Ipsum1}
          \parskip = 3pt

          \lipsum[2]
          \lipsum[4]

      \end{minipage}
  \end{minipage}}

  \colorbox{boxgray}{
  \begin{minipage}{30mm}
      \centering
      \begin{minipage}{.65\linewidth}
          \color{black}
          \textbf{\large Contacts}
          \begin{itemize}
              \parskip = 0pt
              \item Text
              \item Text
          \end{itemize}
      \end{minipage}
  \end{minipage}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.375\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{\Large Lorem Ipsum2}
    \end{center}
    \parskip = 5pt

    \lipsum[1-2]

\end{minipage}\hfill
\end{document}
```

[image: Make columns behave a bit better]